# Creating url with locale doesn't work in Twig

Tags: php, symfony, twig

I am creating a language switcher in Symfony, using the following code:

```
<select title="Change Language" onChange="window.location.href=this.value">
   <option value="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'_locale':'en'}) }}" {% if  app.request.locale == 'en'  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>English                                </option>
  <option value="{{ path(app.request.attributes.get('_route'), {'_locale':'it'}) }}" {% if  app.request.locale == 'it'  %} selected="selected" {% endif %}>Italiano                                </option>
</select>
```

When I go to `http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/en/about` the links in the `option` are correct, i.e: `/app_dev.php/en/about` and `/app_dev.php/it/about` but if I go to the same page without specifying the locale, `http://localhost:8000/app_dev.php/about` incorrect links are created in the `option` like this: `/app_dev.php/about?_locale=it` and `/app_dev.php/about?_locale=en`

The about action in my controller looks like this:

```
 /**
 * @Route("/{_locale}/about", name="aboutUs", defaults={"_locale" = "en"}, requirements={"_locale" = "en|de|fr|es|it"})
 * @Route("/about")
 */

public  function aboutAction(){
    return $this->render('default/frontend/about.html.twig');
}
```

How can I correct this?

Comment: I think you have to remove second route or add default locale to it.

Comment: @malcolm If I remove the second route, then going to /app_dev.php/about results in a 404. Also adding a default locale to it, didn't help...

Comment: So add default locale and requirements, just copy route above and change name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, delete your second @Route.

After, install https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSI18nRoutingBundle
With this bundle, you can do the system URLs like you want.

down you have an example of config that do it.

```
jms_i18n_routing:
    default_locale: en
    locales: [es, it, fr, pl, pt, en, de, ca]
    strategy: prefix_except_default
```

Comment: Ok, Congrats! :-)